# Unexpectly found nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, updating

I'm doing updating for CoreData and I need to load data for editing to textfields. and in AddViewController in viewDidLoad I have

```
if let myData = data {

            knihaTextField.text = data.valueForKey("kniha") as? String
            autorTextField.text = data.valueForKey("autor") as? String
            rokTextField.text = data.valueForKey("rok") as? String
            vydavatelstvoTextField.text = data.valueForKey("vydavatelstvo") as? String
            stranyTextField.text = data.valueForKey("strany") as? String

        }
```

In             knihaTextField.text = data.valueForKey("kniha") as? String I'm getting error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

full code :

http://pastebin.com/yF53nbSE

I'm doing segue from DetailView to PridatView - full code:

http://pastebin.com/BeG4eZHX

Comment: Have u checked the following tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051039/ios-zooming-uiimageview-on-a-uiscrollview

Comment: Do you need all of the values from `myData` or there are cases when some of them can be missing?

Comment: OK, which version of Xcode are you using? I'll post my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys anyway thanks for you help. But I solved it with friend. And decided that it's need to be in viewDidAppear

```
 override public func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let myData = data {
            knihaTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("kniha") as? String
            autorTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("autor") as? String
            rokTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("rok") as? String
            vydavatelstvoTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("vydavatelstvo") as? String
            stranyTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("strany") as? String
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding about how `if let` works here.

Use `myData`, not `data`, after the `if let` statement.

```
if let myData = data {
    knihaTextField.text = myData.valueForKey("kniha") as? String
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's in this block of code?  If so, can you check to make sure all of your text fields are correctly hooked up to the storyboard?  If they are not, then they will be nil and cause a crash because you've defined them as explicitly unwrapped.

Comment: Adding data with PridatViewController is without problem everything is okey. But Updating isn't working. I can upload you project and u can look at it.

Comment: I wonder how it could compile before the change suggested in this answer.

Comment: @appzYourLife Easily, it's an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know if some of your parameters is not nil. You should be doing an optional binding for all of your parameters (in case you always need them all set up). This is how you do a multiple unwrapping as from Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 Beta):

**EDIT**: You can use shorthand syntax to access the values:

```
if let myData = data as? NSDictionary {
    if let kniha = myData["kniha"] as? String, autor = myData["autor"] as? String, 
       rok = myData["rok"] as? String, vydavatelstvo = myData["vydavatelstvo"] as? String, 
       strany = myData["strany"] as? String {
           knihaTextField.text = kniha 
           autorTextField.text = autor
           rokTextField.text = rok
           vydavatelstvoTextField.text = vydavatelstvo
           stranyTextField.text = strany
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be using `myData`.

Comment: but i had variable for myData only in if let myData = data

Comment: you should keep `if let myData = data` because this way you unwrap it knowing that your data is not nil. I will edit my answer once again. Hope this time it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77178/discussion-between-patffo-and-flashadvanced).

Comment: great edit's working but when i want to add its crashing with same error (so adding was working edit not.. and now edit is working and adding not :/ ) and when i press Edit button it isn't showing in textfields writed text that i want to edit only placeholders

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer when it is ignoring that `knihaTextField` is `nil`, which is obvious from the full code. Also, it casts `NSManagedObject` to `NSDictionary` which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

`knihaTextField` is probably `nil`. If you are using Interface Builder, you haven't connected it.

After seeing your code - the problem is in the fact that the text fields are inside cells. When creating cells, you are saving their textfields into variables. However, `viewDidLoad` is typically the first call in a controller, definitely called before table view delegates so all your text fields will be `nil`.

My advice would be to forget `viewDidLoad` and remove all the `UITextField` variables. Instead, you should:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell!.configure("Názov knihy", delegate:self)
    cell!.textField.text = data?.valueForKey("kniha") as? String
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell!.configure("Meno autora", delegate:self)
    cell!.textField.text = data?.valueForKey("autor") as? String
}
```

you can also simplify the code like this

```
let titles = ["Názov knihy", "Meno autora"] //add the other titles here
let propertyKeys = ["kniha", "autor"]   //add the other keys here

cell!.configure(titles[indexPath.row], delegate:self)
cell!.textField.text = data?.valueForKey(propertyKeys[indexPath.row]) as? String
```

If you want to distuingish between several text fields, this is one of the cases when using `UIView.tag` is a simple (not the best) solution.

```
cell!.textField.tag = indexPath.row
```

There are other problems in your code. Typically, table cells are dynamically released and reallocated so you cannot keep references to text fields this way.

Probably the best architecture would be:

1. Have instance variables for every `String` value.
2. In `viewDidLoad` set the variable values from `data`.
3. In `cellForRow` use only the instance variables, don't use `data`.
4. Have a `UITextFieldDelegate` that will save the text values back to your instance variables (using `tag` to distuingish text fields).
5. In `saveTapped` use the instance variables to write back to `data`, don't use textFields.

To be honest, the whole use case would get easier if you removed the `UITableView` and replaced it by `UIScrollView`. Designing the screen in Interface Builder would make it very fast and it would get easier because you wouldn't have a problem with cell reusing. Also, if properly connected, all text fields would be already non-nil in `viewDidLoad`.